# Adding asp controls to programmatically added content

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I would like:

In an ideal scenario I would be able to create an anchor with `oncommand` and `commandargument` attributes, but if I'm not mistaken that doesn't work and you have to create a control, such as a button, where it will work. My problem then comes from wanting to place that button for each item on the page, as I need something to add the control to, but if I created an anchor with `runat="server"` and, say, `id="try"`, I can't then do: `try.Controls.Add(button)` because the anchor 'try' hasn't actually been created yet.

Background:

The majority of content is being added programmatically. A stringbuilder is used to create a string of what will be html displayed on the page. Is it possible to add a control to the page in the middle of this string? OR into an element which is programmatically added this way?

I have tried:

Creating anchors (or otherwise) and targeting the `id` of those elements and then creating a button as follows, but, because the elements are added programmatically and the number required will vary, the `id`s will then be try0, try1, etc:

```
var button = new Button {
  CommandArgument = "test",
  Text = "Try"
};
button.Command += bt_sendMail_tryDevice_Click;
try.Controls.Add(button);
```

So I tried variations of the following, where in my aspx page I have a 'dummy' element with the `id="try"` so it doesn't complain, but I understand why it doesn't like it, at the same time though I don't know how to get around it. (tryCount being an int which increase with each iteration to keep the id unique).

```
this.FindControl(try.ToString() + tryCount.ToString()).Controls.Add(button);
```

Comment: `asp:PlaceHolder` is designed for this use case.  Won't render until a control is added to it (usually programmatically).

Comment: But I can't programmatically add the placeholder can I? I currently use a placeholder for something else in a fixed location, but here I need another placeholder for each row on the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "each row on the page"? do you have a grid view? repeater? Can you add a `LinkButton` to the item template?

Comment: I knew as I wrote row someone would get confused. Ignore that, just know I'm adding more than one in various places. - . Just like with every control, I can't add the `LinkButton` to the page without having somewhere to place it, and because where I want it is being added programmatically, I can't target where I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda hard to tell what your going for, but I will do my best to get as close as I can. The first thing is you need some control to work as a "container". This can be just about any control you like. In my test for this scenario I did something like this:

```
<div runat="server" id="ContainerDiv"></div>
```

The next thing is you need a way to manage your Id. I did this by creating a simple variable and method like so:

```
private int IdCount = 0;
private string GetNewID()
{
    return string.Format("try{0}", IdCount++);
}
```

Now you say you want an achor tag that also has a `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` a `LinkButton` will do this. You can add a `LinkButton` to your div above like this:

```
ContainerDiv.Controls.Add(
    new LinkButton()
    {
        ID = GetNewID(),
        CommandName = "DoSomething",
        CommandArgument = "arg",
        Text= "Try Me",
    });
```

Obviously replacing the `CommandName` and the rest with the values you really want. Just be sure to call `GetNewID()` when assigning the ID so they will always be unique.

Controls can be added to a page anywhere as a child of an existing server control, including the page itself, but doing so can be tricky. Be sure to add them to your page as soon as you can (in the page lifecycle) as post back events may not work correctly.

**Update**

Keeping references to already created elements on your page may simplify your implementation:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    Control containerDiv;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this.containerDiv = SomeMethodThatCreatesADiv();
         this.Page.Controls.Add(containerDiv);
    }

    void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        this.containerDiv.Controls.Add(
            new LinkButton()
            {
                ID = GetNewID(),
                CommandName = "DoSomething",
                CommandArgument = "arg",
                Text= "Try Me",
            });
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is essentially exactly what I've been trying, but my problem is I can't target the element of an id which is made programmatically, i.e. the div where I want the button is created from the code behind, and therefore I can't target the id of that div (even though it's technically created before it's targeted, the intellisense doesn't know that)

Comment: Try keeping a reference to that div, instead of looking it up by ID. I'll update my answer

Comment: What's actually happening here? `this.containerDiv = SomeMethodThatCreatesADiv();` + `this.Page.Controls.Add(containerDiv);`

Comment: Well, I'm making assumptions as to how that div makes it onto your page in the first place, because I don't know. But the idea is to save a reference of the div as it gets added to the page, so you can use it later, instead of searching for an Id.